# Float number cannot read context from discord?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, floating-point, calculator, discord.py

Trying to make a calculator for my website for website currency, the problem is it has floating value it said TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Context'

Making the context as float

```py
@x.command()
async def cal(ctx):
    veela = requests.get('https://veela.csne.host')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(veela.content, 'html.parser')
    ar = ""
    for text in soup.findAll("h2",attrs={'class':'display-3 font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-0 animated fadeIn delay-1s'}):
        ar += f'{text.text}'

    xe = float(ar)+float((ctx))

    print(xe)
    await ctx.send(float(xe))
```

I expect the output for this to work because I tried it on CMD and it works, but it doesn't work for discord.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@x.command()
async def cal(ctx, arg: float):
    veela = requests.get('https://veela.csne.host')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(veela.content, 'html.parser')

    ar = ""
    for text in soup.findAll("h2",attrs={'class':'display-3 font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-0 animated fadeIn delay-1s'}):
        ar += f'{text.text}'
    xe = float(ar)+float((arg))

    print(xe)
    await ctx.send(float(xe))
```

Seem like I got it working